# How to install Shoes GUI framework for Ruby? .install file

Tags: software-installation, gui, ruby

I want to install Shoes framework for Ruby but when I went to their website and downloaded it all I got was a file with `.install` at the end.

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you download Shoes from their [website](http://shoesrb.com/downloads/), you will get a files like `shoes-3.2.23-gtk2-i686.install` which is actually a shell script. You have to make it executable before you can run it. So open a terminal window by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>T</kbd>  and navigate to the folder where you have downloaded the file. Normally it should be in the `Downloads` directory. So type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

to go to `downloads`.

Once you are in the directory containing the install file, run the following command to make it executable:

```
chmod +x shoes-3.2.23-gtk2-i686.install
```

You will be asked to enter your password. After this has been done, run the installer by:

```
./shoes-3.2.23-gtk2-i686.install
```